# Minimization of the Knapsack 01 using dynamic programming

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming, knapsack-problem

I'd like to know if it is possible to use the **knapsack 01 problem** to solve a **minimization problem**. It is possible?
This is the maximization version of the knapsack 01.

```
KNAPSACK01(values, weights, W)
    n = values.length
    Let V[0...n, 0...W] be a new table
    for i = 0 to n
        V[i, 0] = 0
    for w = 0 to W
        V[0, w] = 0
    for i = 1 to n
        for w = 1 to W
            if weights[i] > w
                V[i, w] = V[i - 1, w]
            else 
                if V[i - 1, w - weights[i]] + values[i] > V[i - 1, w]
                    V[i, w] = V[i - 1, w - weights[i]] + values[i]
                else
                    V[i, w] = V[i - 1, w]
    return V[n, W]
```

Comment: Minimize the value of objects instead of maximizing it, by filling the knapsack.

Comment: You need to specify the problem better. To minimize the value you don't take anything, so result value is 0. If you have to take something, take the item with least value. If you have negative values, then multiply them all by -1 and you have a maximization problem again.